# Finding the projection of a cycle polygon with maximum area and no intersections

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a polygon (forming a loop) embedded in euclidean space of dimension 3 or higher, how to find the 2d projection maximizing its area and such that it doesn't intersect ?

My initial idea was to project it onto its top 2 principal components. The problem is that sometimes I end up with intersections, as illustrated below (the topology is a loop, there is no node with degree higher than 2)

[image: 2d projection of a polygon embedded in higher dimensions]

Example 3d loop coordinates:

```
  [[4.97949849, 0.75942183, 1.31840654],
   [5.01604652, 0.41024688, 1.32037069],
   [5.02199246, 0.13215937, 1.41772689],
   [5.01460688, 0.82018837, 1.65609695],
   [4.98041011, 1.50673458, 1.89084445],
   [4.91921092, 2.19662532, 2.12121944],
   [4.88974091, 2.87854221, 2.35856586],
   [4.86793956, 3.56038842, 2.59830211],
   [4.85402615, 4.22211598, 2.82629125],
   [5.26024892, 4.00419726, 3.03558403],
   [5.16132374, 3.5696769 , 2.69162948],
   [5.04524158, 3.09460622, 2.37861492],
   [4.9248038 , 2.58597001, 2.08011595],
   [4.78177256, 2.05429724, 1.79949778],
   [4.79412246, 1.58067165, 1.55518281],
   [4.89434871, 1.15398605, 1.38279877]]
```

Comment: You could try the planes perpendicular to the eigenvectors of the inertia matrix, but I'm not sure that will give the best result.